# Eclipse CDT content assist method parameter hints popup location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to change the location of where Eclipse presents the popup that shows the parameter hints. Default is upper right. I would like it to be lower right as to not block viewing the line above.

I've seen a way to tell Eclipse where to present a popup but maybe it was not for the parameter hints.